# Updating value of define function

Tags: php

```
define("product","hello how are you",TRUE);
$a = constant("product");
<input type="text" name="aa"size="30" value="<?php echo $a;?>">
```

This text field contains the value

```
hello how are you.
```

Question:

When I edit the text in this *aa* field and click the button the value of define function is update accordingly.

Comment: Without define function you can show by assigning variables.

Comment: A define value by 'definition' cannot be changed. It's a constant, constant mean constant.

Answer (score 0):

Do not define something as constant, then attempt on updating it. Definition and usage by W3Schools.com:

Constants are much like variables, except for the following differences:

- **A constant's value cannot be changed after it is set**
- Constant names do not need a leading dollar sign ($)
- Constants can be accessed regardless of scope
- Constant values can only be strings and numbers

You can however update the $a variable to something else. If you're attempting to create an input to change the variable you need to do something like:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="aa" size="30" value="<?=$a?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<?php if(isset($_POST)) {
   $a = $_POST['aa'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You can just put $a = 'Something'; and you can rewrite it further down the code, $a = 'replaced'; I think you're attempting to update the variable with a submit, so create a <form method="post"> element, inside the inputs and a submit button, then create a PHP check <?php if(isset($_POST)) { $a = $_POST['input-name']; } ?>. I updated the answer.

Comment: You are updating $a. But you can't just write something on an input field and expect PHP to change it on keystrokes unless you pass it forward with the $_POST method.